# Question about the group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory, direct-sum

Let $G$ be a group and let $k[G]$ be the group algebra of $G$. If we let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $T=\{t_1,...,t_n\}$ a right transversal for $H$, then we can write
$$
G=\bigcup_{i=1}^nHt_i.
$$
My question is, does this imply that we can write the group algebra as
$$
k[G]=\bigoplus_{i=1}^nk[Ht_i],
$$
where $k[Ht_i]$ is the group algebra of the subgroup $Ht_i$?

Comment: Morally, yes, but this has some grammatical problems that suggest caution. Most importantly, $Ht_i$ is not usually a subgroup; you really want something like $\bigoplus k[H]t_i$, where we are sort of thinking of each summand as literally just a copy of $k[H]$ and the extra "$t_i$" is just a formal variable that helps us keep track of which copy we're in. Second, we don't usually write direct sums of rings, but instead products. There's more to say on the matter, but I'm a bit tired so I'll see if someone else wants to expand into an Answer :)

Comment: @EricNathanStucky, that's fair, thanks for your input. :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, cosets $Ht$ are not subgroups (unless $t\in H$, of course), so we wouldn't write something like $k[Ht]$ in the sense of group algebras. The notation $k[H]t$ makes sense, though, as the image of $k[H]$ under right-multiplication-by-$t$, i.e. $\{at\mid a\in k[H]\}$. We could also use the notation $kHt$ and interpret it as the free vector space spanned by $Ht$ within $k[G]$ (assuming we're treating $G$ itself as a $k$-vector space basis for the group algebra $k[G]$). Thus, for instance, if $H=\{h_1,h_2,h_3,\cdots\}$ then the elements of $k[H]t$ or $kHt$ are linear combinations of $h_1t,h_2t,h_3t,\cdots$.

And yes, the fact we can partition $G$ into cosets does mean we can write

$$ k[G]=\bigoplus_{t\in T} k[H]t $$

as $k$-vector spaces, and indeed as left $k[H]$-modules (aka $H$-reps).